# Web Search Automation with Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web, search, bots

[image]I'm trying to access a search box on a website and I keep getting a 'not JSON serializable' error.

Not quite sure what I am doing wrong should be pretty simple, can anyone spot the issue, is it because I haven't set a specific file path for 'webdriver.Chrome()' or is it because the website has a cookie pop-up that I need to act before the search box will be accessible?

```
# Import necessary libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

# Set up the webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Navigate to the website and search for the product
driver.get("https://www.example")
search_bar = driver.find_element(id, "search-term")
search_bar.send_keys("test")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: it's very difficult to say anything about the cause of the error, Please provide the URL you're trying if it's public, or at least some HTML snippets so that people can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
search_bar = driver.find_element(id, "search-term")
```

You are passing the builtin function `id` to the `.find_element` method, but that's not a valid argument for the first parameter of `.find_element`.

What you probably want is:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# ...
search_bar = driver.find_element(By.ID, "search-term")
```

Comment: Cheers sytech! That solved the issue, I'm assuming By.ID wont work with classes? Would that literally be By.CLASS or is there another method I need to import from the selenium webdriver?

Comment: `By.CLASS_NAME` @T1m_McG -- also check out https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: That's awesome, I'll definitely give it a read, thank you for the help though, much appreciated!